# Processing clicks of 2 buttons in PIC16F84

Tags: assembly, interrupt, pic

I'm stuck in processing clicks of 2 buttons via interrupts using PIC16F84.

Schematic capture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqWxX.png)

Firmware:

```
#include p16f84a.inc


RST   code  0x0 
goto  Start
code 0x4 
goto LED_STATUS  

v_counter equ 0x2E
constant c_led_status=0x20
constant inc_value = 0x1

PGM   code
Start
   CLRF PORTB
   CLRF v_counter
   BSF STATUS,RP0 

   MOVLW 0x81 
   MOVWF TRISB

   BCF STATUS,RP0 
   CLRF INTCON 
   BSF INTCON,INTE 
   BSF INTCON,GIE 

Loop  
   goto  Loop

LED_STATUS
   MOVLW c_led_status  
   XORWF PORTB,1 

   MOVLW inc_value
   ADDWF v_counter,1

   ADDWF PORTB,1 

   BCF INTCON,INTF 
   BSF INTCON,GIE 

RETURN 

END
```

This is simple counter which increments value in memory by clicking on button and shows it on display. My goal is adding another button which adds `2` to value in memory. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to determine which button was pushed, so if you have only a single interrupt pin available, you will need to wire each button to its own pin in the input port, and use a wired- or gated-OR to drive the interrupt signal.  If you don't want that complexity, you could just poll the two buttons periodically (which would also give you an easy way to implement a software debounce).